# What is a "moist" salt?

Tags: salt

I have been looking into buying some gourmet salt, and several of them are described as being "moist salt".   What does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moist salts are naturally harvested sea salts from which not all the water has been removed.   They are noticeably wet, often caking up or forming more of a "slush" than a powder.

Some aficionados only believe that sea salt is "real" and "natural" if it is moist.  Me, I have enough humidity in the apartment.

Comment: +1 for your apartment :-) (Maybe you should be looking for another)

Answer (score 2):

They have some humidity in them. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sel_gris), up to 13% of moisture is acceptable.